# Does ServerFault plan on blocking ads placed by GoDaddy because of their support of SOPA?

Tags: discussion

ServerFault is currently running ads that link to GoDaddy.

In the spirit of [this question on MetaSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116891/will-stackoverflow-boycott-godaddy-because-of-their-support-for-sopa), does ServerFault plan on stop running the ad?

[image: GoSOPA's ads being run on SF]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would imagine that, since all of the sites are owned by the same company, if (when) they stop running them on one site then they will be pulled from all of the sites.

Also, see [**this similar question on MetaSO**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116938/stack-overflow-showing-advertisements-from-godaddy-really).

Comment: That questions contains the following response from Waffles: Well, clearly we have to honour prior commercial agreements we have. I have alerted the team and we will deal with this in due coarse. – waffles♦ 27 mins ago

Comment: Then that's your answer, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this answer from [Joel Spolsky says it all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116918/131874):

> ## Yes.

However, that was posted *before* [anyone had read this](http://www.godaddy.com/newscenter/release-view.aspx?news_item_id=378&isc=smtwsup)

> Go Daddy No Longer Supports SOPA Looks to Internet Community & Fellow
>   Tech Leaders to Develop Legislation We All Support
>
> SCOTTSDALE, Ariz. (Dec. 23, 2011) - Go Daddy is no longer supporting
>   SOPA, the "Stop Online Piracy Act" currently working its way through
>   U.S. Congress.

So, I'm going to now guess, no.

Comment: If you read it carefully, the statement from godaddy, was obviously crafted by a politician (*cheating lying bastard* R US).

Comment: @Iain - not sure what relevance it has who wrote it? You can't get much more clearer than `Go Daddy is no longer supporting SOPA`

Comment: Oh dear and you an Aussie too - to quote @voretaq7 in chat earlier "Go Daddy will support it when and if the Internet community supports it.” I think this was the most telling remark. They still support it. They just won't say they do until everyone else does. Nothing quite like a wishy-washy company with no set ground to control your website.

Comment: Also not quite sure what being an Aussie has to do with anything either?

Comment: I believe Aussies to be famously capable of detecting politician's double speak - after all you put yours underground (best place for them) :)

Comment: Its always amazed me that anyone did business with them in the first place. Given the amount of problems with them that I've read about over the years, using their services has seemed too much like trying to build a working nuclear reactor out of lego.

Answer (score 1):

Could we please try to keep politics out of here and local politics especially? Once you head down that road there's no turning back.